# How to know the name of the an active preset dropdown?

Tags: python

Hello i created a custom operator preset system.

i'd like to know how to have acces to the name of an active preset. i think an example from any preset in blender could help me in my research.

There's no info about this anywhere.

Here is my set up[image]

This is the code i was able to collect so far

```
#this is the correct code mut within blender ! no with my addon
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].preset_name = "New Preset"
#call preset menu of nlender ! not my addon
bpy.ops.wm.call_panel(name="CYCLES_PT_sampling_presets")

#add a new preset
bpy.ops.scatter.custom_slot_preset_add_operator(name="Wow", remove_name=False, remove_active=False)
#execute a preset from my addon
bpy.ops.script.execute_preset(filepath="filepathofthepreset", menu_idname="Scatter_MT_C_Slots_PresetMenu")
#call preset menu 
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="Scatter_MT_C_Slots_PresetMenu")
```

i need to find the 
**bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].preset_name = "New Preset"**
for my addon menu. i don't know how this is possible ?

Comment: You mean this bpy.context.workspace.name and [ws.name for ws in bpy.data.workspaces]?

Comment: @lemon sorry for being unclear. i was referencing drop down presets.

Comment: @lemon i updated the question/descritption

Comment: I'm not skilled at that. But why don't you store the preset identification/name/whatever as an operator property? (not sure there is some Blender mechanism that does it automatically, except maybe by preset path).

Comment: It’s the bl_label of the preset menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AFWS

```
print(bpy.types.CYCLES_PT_integrator_presets.bl_label)
```

active preset is in fact the name of the bl_label

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of [DB3D](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/54991/db3d):

Assuming that panel for the preset uses `preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"` the selected preset is indeed stored in `bl_label`. This can be seen in `class ExecutePreset(Operator)` in the [`presets.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/presets.py$243) where the label is changed to the most recent selection when the operator is executed.

```
    # change the menu title to the most recently chosen option
    preset_class = getattr(bpy.types, self.menu_idname)
    preset_class.bl_label = bpy.path.display_name(basename(filepath))
```

<sub>The code is licensed under GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3</sub>